# sql query for checking the prefix,post-fix or complete value

Tags: mysql, sql

**I am expecting to get 1 record but presently  I am getting 0 records by using below query. How to make it work?** Basically, I am searching in the table with a keyword, if prefix, postfix, the exact value of the keyword matches with table value then records should return. Basically, i am using this table to disallow unreal name if match found with this table value

**case 1**: should return a record because `sex`is present in the prefix of the search keyword

```
select name from invalid_names_master where
name LIKE '%sexsadf' OR
name LIKE 'sexsadf%' OR
name='sexsadf'
```

**case 2**: should return a record because `sex`is present in the postfix of the search keyword

```
select name from invalid_names_master where
name LIKE '%ertsex' OR
name LIKE 'ertsex%' OR
name='ertsex'
```

In both the above 2 cases

**Expected output** :

```
`sex`  (i.e 1 record found)
```

---

**Table:** invalid_name_master
[image]

Comment: The queries in the question do what they are supposed to do: search for sexsadf or ertsex. Mysql is not a mind reader to figure out that for you any values containing only sex are fine. If that's what you want to find, then this is what you need to search for.

Comment: why negative vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you intend to do reverse, *i.e.*, if the input string `sexsadf` contains any value from the `invalid_name_master`, you flag it.

Try the following query instead:

```
select name 
from invalid_names_master 
where
  'sexsadf' LIKE CONCAT('%', name) OR 
  'sexsadf' LIKE CONCAT(name, '%') OR 
  'sexsadf' LIKE name
```

Comment: Thank you! I was exactly this one!

Comment: @AshutoshSingh because of images I think. For next time, Refer this link on how to frame a good SQL question: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 1):

You should simply use `like`:

```
select name
from invalid_names_master
where 'sexsadf' like concat('%', name, '%');
```

One condition is sufficient.

Comment: No ! it did not work as expected, I only wanted to match through prefix and postfix... ` i.e I don't want to match 'asexadf'   > here in middle sex is there your answer is returning search result for this also`